# Regular expressions to delete things from the first line in multiple txt files

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, batch-file

I searched the internet for days trying to fix this myself but didn't succeed. I can not show any code because everything I tried was just wrong. So my question is maybe a bit long, but I hope someone can help me with it.

I got a folder that contains a lot of `.txt` files with scraped data (1000+). Now I would like a script that loops through all this files, changes the first line and then saves the files again. On the first line of a `.txt` file, there is a title. But I want certain things to be removed from that title. Here are a few **first line examples** from 5 different `.txt` files:

```
Hello world my name is awesome, but you knew that video c5
Hello world my name is awesome  video3 v: Everybody knows I am r
Hello world my name is awesome: It got 100 likes in 10 min 1f
Hello world my name is awesome 43 video 2: Did you know that:
Hello world my name is awesome a3: It is Mr smokealot 1f,
```

I think I covered all possible combinations that are present. What I would like is that only this part `Hello world my name is awesome` stays in every file on the first line and the rest must be deleted. I also got text on the other lines in the `.txt` files, but those must stay untouched. Every title is different per `.txt` file but I used `Hello world my name is awesome` to show wich part of the first line contains the title.

I think that these are the things that must be done to fix the titles for me.

1. Delete all character after the first coma or colon including the coma and colon itself.
2. Delete all the words and letters that contain a number in it like a3 in the  fifth **first line examples**.
3. Delete all the numbers.
4. Delete the word video.
5. Delete all single characters except for the letter "I". This is to remove the "v" from the second **first line example**

When this is done I would like to save the file on the current place with the current name.

Is this possible?

Comment: How is the string-to-be-retained defined? Will the result be that each of the target text files will have the same first line?

Comment: If all the Titles are different how are we supposed to know what to keep and what to delete?

Comment: @Magoo No, every first line is different. Because all the titles are different.

Comment: @Squashman Almost every title ends with a comma or colon. So everything to the right of this must be deleted. And then there are numbers and words with numbers in it that need to be deleted.

Comment: @rojo When I run that line it gives me a lot of errors. Is there maybe a typo in the command? Or maybe I am doing something wrong?  I would like to only keep  `Hello world my name is awesome`.  I wish I could re-scrape it, but it's done by a program and I can't change that

Comment: `powershell "gci *.txt | %{ $i = 0; (gc $_.FullName) | %{ if ($i) { $_ } else { $_ -replace \"\s+\w*\d+\w*\"; $i = 1 } } | out-file $_.FullName }"` would remove all words containing numerals plus their preceding spaces from the first line of *.txt. This should leave you with `Hello world my name is awesome, but you knew that`.  (Previous comment, I was missing a set of parentheses around `(gc $_.FullName)`.  Sorry about that.)  That command is formatted for the cmd console.  If including in a batch script, you need to double both occurrences of the `%` symbols.

Comment: @rojo Nice this is almost what I want. But if possible can you maybe change it for me so that it only keeps `Hello world my name is awesome`. It would help me out a lot if you could make it work with the new examples I gave in the question. I tried to edit your command myself but without success

Comment: What I'm struggling to understand is, why do you want a regex at all?  Why not just replace line 1 of *.txt with flat text `Hello world my name is awesome`?  That would be much easier.

Comment: @rojo Because every title is different per .txt file. But I used `Hello world my name is awesome` to show wich part of the first line contains the title.

Comment: You're asking an awful lot, xyz.  We're here to help fix broken things and hopefully to share knowledge, wisdom, and insight, and to teach; not to manage your project from `@echo off` to `goto :EOF`.  You know the old saying.  Build a man a fire and he'll be warm for a day.  Set a man on fire and he'll be warm for the rest of his life.  We want you to be warm for the rest of your life.

Comment: @rojo I understand that it maybe a bit too much to ask. I like that old saying, it's a good one.  Thanks for the help so far I will try to tweak the command you gave me. If I succeed I will post my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

REGEX Support of Batch is very restricted (only implemented in `findstr`, but a very small subset).So let's do it (nearly) without REGEX:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM t.txt contains your first-line-examples
for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do call :getTitle %%a

goto :eof

:getTitle
set title=%*
REM get rid of all characters after (including) comma or colon:
for /f "delims=,:" %%a in ("%title%") do set title=%%a

REM get rid of every word with numbers and anything after it:
set "line="
for %%a in (%title%) do (
  REM if the word contains a number, Exit the Loop, else add the word to the line:
  echo %%a|findstr "[0-9]" >nul && goto :endOfTitle ||set line=!line! %%a
  )
:endOfTitle

REM get rid of the leading space (included with the SET in the last FOR)
if defined line set line=%line:~1%

echo(%line%
```

Contents of t.txt:

```
Hello world my name is awesome, but you knew that video c5
Hello world my name is awesome  video3 v: Everybody knows I am r
Hello world my name is awesome: It got 100 likes in 10 min 1f
Hello world my name is awesome 43 video 2: Did you know that:
Hello world my name is awesome a3: It is Mr smokealot 1f,
Hello world my name is John Doe, but you knew that video5c
Hello world my name is Jane Doe  video3v: but you knew that
Hello world my name is Superman: but you knew that 1f
Hello world my name is Asterix, Gallier 43: but you knew that 1f
34: this is obviously an invalid title
Any string is a title until it hits a comma or colon, this is scrap
Any word that contains a number ends the title l1ke this one
```

Output:

```
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is John Doe
Hello world my name is Jane Doe
Hello world my name is Superman
Hello world my name is Asterix

Any string is a title until it hits a comma or colon
Any word that contains a number ends the title
```

(@Mofi: I included some of your examples - I like the names :) )

**EDIT** to process all files in the current Folder

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM for all .txt files in the current folder do:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do call :process "%%a"
goto :eof

:process
set file=%1
REM get first line of this file:
set /p first=<%1

REM 
call :getTitle %first%

REM when %line% is empty, skip the edit:
if defined line (
  echo %line% >"%~n1.tmp"
  more +1 %file% >>"%~n1.tmp"
  @ECHO move /y "%~n1.tmp" "%file%"
)
goto :eof

:getTitle
set title=%*

REM get rid of all characters after (including) comma or colon:
for /f "delims=,:" %%a in ("%title%") do set title=%%a

REM get rid of every word with numbers and anything after it:
set "line="
for %%a in (%title%) do (
  REM if the word contains a number, Exit the Loop, else add the word to the line:
  echo %%a|findstr "[0-9]" >nul && goto :endOfTitle ||set line=!line! %%a
  )
:endOfTitle

REM get rid of the leading space (included with the SET in the last FOR):
if defined line set line=%line:~1%

goto :eof
```

Remove the `@ECHO` if you are satisfied with the Output.

Comment: @Mofi has a nice twist on this. I'm almost there now. I only miss one part. And that is to let this script loop through  a folder with a lot of `.txt` files then change the first line to keep only the title and then saves the `.txt` files with the same name they had before. I tried it myself. But it's just too hard for me. I would appreciate it very much if you or maybe someone else could help me with it. If not, I understand. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @Stephan It's very nice by you answering second question on how to use the subroutine `GetTitle` on all text files in a directory here in your answer. +1 by me for this extra work with very smart coded file loop.

Answer (score 0):

I created the text file `Test.txt` with following content:

```
Hello world my name is John Doe, but you knew that video5c
Hello world my name is Jane Doe  video3v: but you knew that
Hello world my name is Superman: but you knew that 1f
Hello world my name is Asterix, Gallier 43: but you knew that 1f
34: but you knew that this is an invalid title
, but you knew that this is also an invalid title
 but you knew that this is an invalid title, too
```

Then I developed following commented batch file to evaluate all the title lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FileTitle="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("Test.txt") do (
    call :GetTitle "%%L"
    echo Get from  "%%L"
    echo the title "!FileTitle!"
    echo.
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:GetTitle
set "Line=%~1"

rem Replace the string " but you knew that" case insensitive
rem by character # with a comma before which is always removed.

set "Line=%Line: but you knew that=,#%"

rem Use character # as separator to get everything left of this character.

for /F "tokens=1 delims=#" %%T in ("%Line%") do set "FileTitle=%%T"
if "%FileTitle%" == "," goto TitleError
set "FileTitle=%FileTitle:~0,-1%"

:RemoveSpaces
if "%FileTitle%" == "" goto TitleError
if "%FileTitle:~-1%" == " " set "FileTitle=%FileTitle:~0,-1%" & goto RemoveSpaces

rem Is the last character a comma, remove this character, too.

if "%FileTitle:~-1%" == "," (
    set "FileTitle=%FileTitle:~0,-1%"
    if "!FileTitle!" == "" goto TitleError
    goto RemoveSpaces
)

rem Is the last character not a colon, we have the file title.

if not "%FileTitle:~-1%" == ":" goto :EOF

rem Otherwise remove the colon and the word left to the
rem colon if this word contains also at least 1 digit.

set "FileTitle=%FileTitle:~0,-1%"
set "LastWord="

rem The first condition in code below should be never true according to
rem provided sample data, but it is necessary to avoid an endless loop.

:RemoveWord
if "%FileTitle%" == "" goto TitleError
if "%FileTitle:~-1%" == " " goto EvaluateWord
set "LastWord=%FileTitle:~-1%%LastWord%"
set "FileTitle=%FileTitle:~0,-1%"
goto RemoveWord

:EvaluateWord
for /L %%C in (0,1,9) do (
    if not "!LastWord:%%C=!" == "%LastWord%" goto RemoveSpaces
)

rem Append the removed word as it does not contain a digit.
rem Then we have the file title and can exit the subroutine.

set "FileTitle=%FileTitle%%LastWord%"
goto :EOF

:TitleError
set "FileTitle=Error: No file title found^!"
goto :EOF
```

This batch file executed in a command prompt window outputs:

```
Get from  "Hello world my name is John Doe, but you knew that video5c"
the title "Hello world my name is John Doe"

Get from  "Hello world my name is Jane Doe  video3v: but you knew that"
the title "Hello world my name is Jane Doe"

Get from  "Hello world my name is Superman: but you knew that 1f"
the title "Hello world my name is Superman"

Get from  "Hello world my name is Asterix, Gallier 43: but you knew that 1f"
the title "Hello world my name is Asterix, Gallier"

Get from  "34: but you knew that this is an invalid title"
the title "Error: No file title found!"

Get from  ", but you knew that this is also an invalid title"
the title "Error: No file title found!"

Get from  " but you knew that this is an invalid title, too"
the title "Error: No file title found!"
```

The function `GetTitle` in this batch file uses massively string substitutions with the commands **FOR** and **SET** to determine each title.

Use the function `GetTitle` if the output is what you expect for those lines.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`

---

My next version using updated example data:

```
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome, but you knew that video c5
Hello world my name is awesome  video3 v: Everybody knows I am r
Hello world my name is awesome: It got 100 likes in 10 min 1f
Hello world my name is awesome 43 video 2: Did you know that:
Hello world my name is awesome a3: It is Mr smokealot 1f,
```

The batch code is now much easier than before with the first time defined rules:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FileTitle="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("Test.txt") do (
    call :GetTitle "%%L"
    echo Get from  "%%L"
    echo the title "!FileTitle!"
    echo.
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:GetTitle

rem Get string left from first comma or first colon. The entire line
rem is returned if the line does not contain any comma or colon.

for /F "tokens=1 delims=,:" %%T in ("%~1") do set "WordsList=%%T"

rem Process each word from list and check for containing any digit, or being
rem a single letter different than upper case "I", or being the word "video".
rem Those words are ignored on building the file title from the words list.
rem It is expected here that non of the words contain a non word character
rem as this could result in a syntax error on processing the words.

set "FileTitle="
for %%I in (%WordsList%) do (
    set "Skip=0"
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%W in ("#%%I#") do set "Word=%%W"
    if "!Word!" NEQ "#%%I#" set "Skip=1"
    set "Word=%%I"
    if "!Word:~0,1!" EQU "%%I" (
        if "%%I" NEQ "I" set "Skip=1"
    )
    if /I "%%I" EQU "video" set "Skip=1"
    if "!Skip!" EQU "0" set "FileTitle=!FileTitle! %%I"
)

rem Was there not at least 1 valid word found?

if "%FileTitle%" == "" set "FileTitle= Error: No file title found."

rem Remove the leading space and exit subroutine GetTitle.
set "FileTitle=%FileTitle:~1%"
goto :EOF
```

The output for the example input data is:

```
Get from  "Hello world my name is awesome"
the title "Hello world my name is awesome"

Get from  "Hello world my name is awesome, but you knew that video c5"
the title "Hello world my name is awesome"

Get from  "Hello world my name is awesome  video3 v: Everybody knows I am r"
the title "Hello world my name is awesome"

Get from  "Hello world my name is awesome: It got 100 likes in 10 min 1f"
the title "Hello world my name is awesome"

Get from  "Hello world my name is awesome 43 video 2: Did you know that:"
the title "Hello world my name is awesome"

Get from  "Hello world my name is awesome a3: It is Mr smokealot 1f,"
the title "Hello world my name is awesome"
```

---

And here is one more version which is very similar to version of [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FileTitle="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("Test.txt") do (
    call :GetTitle "%%L"
    echo !FileTitle!
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:GetTitle

rem Get string left from first comma or first colon. The entire line
rem is returned if the line does not contain any comma or colon.

for /F "tokens=1 delims=,:" %%T in ("%~1") do set "WordsList=%%T"

rem Process each word from list and check for containing any digit, or being
rem a single letter different than upper case "I", or being the word "video".
rem Those words are ignored and all other remaining words on building the
rem file title from the words list. It is expected here that non of the words
rem contain a non word character as this could result in a syntax error on
rem processing the words.

set "FileTitle="
for %%I in (%WordsList%) do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%W in ("#%%I#") do set "Word=%%W"
    if "!Word!" NEQ "#%%I#" goto CheckTitle
    set "Word=%%I"
    if "!Word:~0,1!" EQU "%%I" (
        if "%%I" NEQ "I" goto CheckTitle
    )
    if /I "%%I" EQU "video" goto CheckTitle
    set "FileTitle=!FileTitle! %%I"
)

:CheckTitle
rem Was there not at least 1 valid word found?

if "%FileTitle%" == "" set "FileTitle= Error: No file title found."

rem Remove the leading space and exit subroutine GetTitle.
set "FileTitle=%FileTitle:~1%"
goto :EOF
```

The output on example input data posted in [Stephan´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34207369/3074564) is:

```
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is awesome
Hello world my name is John Doe
Hello world my name is Jane Doe
Hello world my name is Superman
Hello world my name is Asterix
Error: No file title found.
Any string is
Any word that contains
```

The difference to output produced by Stephan´s code is that a single character word not being `I` results in exiting the words processing loop and therefore truncating the title at this word.

This single character word behavior can be changed by removing the code lines:

```
    set "Word=%%I"
    if "!Word:~0,1!" EQU "%%I" (
        if "%%I" NEQ "I" goto CheckTitle
    )
```

Then the output of this third batch code would be same as what batch code written by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) produces with the exception of an error message instead of a blank line.

---

PS: This is a good example what happens if a questioner does not make it clear what the output data should be for provided input data by posting also in question the expected output data.

Comment: This is almost what I want. But now it searches for this specific string " but you knew that" and that part of the line is always random. I updated my question. I hope that it is clearer now and hope you can help me further with this because you almost got it. I will definitely look at those commands after work. Thanks

Comment: `This is a good example what happens ...` - that is an even better example that analyzing your problem is even more important than your actual programming skills.

Comment: Thanks for this script it is exactly what I was looking for to change the first line of my `.txt` files. Now I tried hard this weekend to fix the last part myself. That is to let this script loop through a folder with a lot of `.txt` files then change the first line to keep only the title and then saves the `.txt` files with the same name they had before. But it's just too hard for me. I spend so many hours trying to fix the last part but without success :(. I would appreciate it very much if you could me with that or maybe someone else? If not, I understand thanks for the help so far!